# leer todos los metodos de un controller en una web API de c#

Tags: c#, reactjs, webapi

estoy tratando de consumir una api escrita en c# que tiene un controller y varios metodos en el, quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de hacer fetch a ese controller y obtener todos los metodos que tiene guardados para luego acceder a ellos mediante el mismo objeto, el codigo del controller es el siguiente:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductoController : ControllerBase
    {
        public readonly ShopApiContext _shopApiContext;

        public ProductoController(ShopApiContext _context)
        {
            _shopApiContext = _context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Lista")]
        public IActionResult Lista()
        {
            List<Producto> lista = new List<Producto>();
            try
            {
                lista = _shopApiContext.Productos.Include(c => c.oCategoria).ToList();
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new {mensaje = "ok", response = lista});
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new { mensaje = ex.Message, response = lista });
                throw;
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Obtener/{Idproducto:int}")]
        public IActionResult Obtener(int Idproducto)
        {
            Producto oProducto = _shopApiContext.Productos.Find(Idproducto);
            if (oProducto == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Producto no encontrado");
            }

            try
            {
                oProducto = _shopApiContext.Productos.Include(c => c.oCategoria).Where(p => p.Idproducto == Idproducto).FirstOrDefault();

                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new { mensaje = "ok", response = oProducto });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new { mensaje = ex.Message, response = oProducto });
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

y en la app de react que lo estoy tratando de obtener es esta:

```
import './App.css';
import imageRickMorty from './img/rick-morty.png'
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Characters from './components/characters';

function App() {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState(null)

  const reqAPI = async() => {
    //const api = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character')
    const api2 = await fetch('http://localhost:5189/api/Producto')
    //const charactersAPI = await api.json()
    const charactersAPI = await api2.json()
    //setCharacters(charactersAPI.results)
    setCharacters(charactersAPI)
  }

  console.log(characters)
```

el resultado de ese fetch es undefined, si le pongo la direccion de uno de los metodos directamente funciona bien, pero me gustaria saber si hay alguna manera de guardar en characters algo asi como todo lo que tiene el controller para acceder a los metodos a traves del mismo objeto character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS).

Si tienes muchas rutas en un controlador tendrías que dividirlo en otros y limitar tu options a los casos que soporte el controlador en concreto.

```
namespace BookingApp.Presentation.Controllers;
[Route("api/hotels/collection")]
[ApiController]
public class HotelsCollectionController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IServiceManager _service;

    public HotelsCollectionController(IServiceManager service) => 
        _service = service ?? 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));

    [HttpOptions]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    public IActionResult GetBaseHotelCollectionoptions()
    {
        Response.Headers.Add(
           "Allow",
           "GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, POST");

        return Ok();
    }
    //*.........................*//    
}
```

Por lo que cuando llames a HTTP Options /api/hotels/collection te devolvera en el header Allow ese valor del controlador. Que problema sucede? solo podras tener un Options por ruta base por lo que deberias dividir el controlador en otros mas si necesitas darle mas soporte al HttpOptions y otras rutas especificas.

Puedes usar de referencia la implementacion de mi [repo de GitHub](https://github.com/sosalejandro/BookingApp/blob/master/BookingApp.Presentation/Controllers/HotelsCollectionController.cs).

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: gracias por tu contribucion, sucede que no entiendo como HttpOptions me podria ayudar en mi situacion, basicamente lo que yo intento hacer es que al hacer el fetch a la API me devuelva todos los metodos que contiene un controlador dado, para no tener que hacer un fetcha a la API cada vez que tenga que invocar algun metodo, no se si me explico. Gracias

Comment: Vale, hans. He actualizado mi respuesta con mayor contenido al respecto.